# use slideDown in ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, slidedown

I'm struggling with how to properly apply the `slideDown` animation to newly added content only.

The code below loads all content with slidedown animation every 200ms which kinda looked silly.

```
//load page every 200ms
setTimeout(function () {
    updates();
}, 200);

//get data
function updates() {
    $.getJSON("fetchdata.php", function (data) {
        $("ul").empty();
        $.each(data.result, function () {
            $("ul").append("<li>post: " + this['msg'] + "</li>");
            $("ul").hide().slideDown('slow');
        });
    });
}
```

Comment: So actually what you want is to `slideDown` the next `li` element that appends `ul` ?

Comment: exactly. but instead it slides all the content. i only want the latest <ul> or <li>

Comment: You should not retrieve the whole data each time. Try to get only the new data (by passing a parameter or something) and append it to the `ul`. Then only slideDown the new added `li`. You might also want to use [comet](http://webscepter.com/simple-comet-implementation-using-php-and-jquery/) to get data only when there is some new.

Comment: as @Brewal suggests, you should modify your php function to return only new data